# Create instance of generic class parameter

Tags: typescript, generics

I want to create an instance of `T` in a generic class in Typescript.
The following code is something I thought would work, but unfortunately it does not.

```
type Constructor<T> = { new(...args: any[]): T };
class Bar { }
class Foo<T extends Constructor<T>> {

    constructor( /* some parameters here, but NOT a type creator! */ ) {}

    create(): T {
        return new T();
    }
}
const bar: Bar = new Foo<Bar>().create();
```

Well there are some other questions/answers here on SO, but all use some kind of type creator that needs to be passed to the generic class/function, like so:

```
function create<T>(creator: new() => T): T {
    return new creator();
}
const bar: Bar = create<Bar>(Bar);
```

But my ctor needs to not have something like that. The `create` function should always stay parameter-less. Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Why must `create` be parameterless? Can you pass the `creator` parameter instead to the constructor of the `Foo` class? You have to pass the constructor of your class `T` into `Foo` somehow, one way or another, or this won't work. Try considering how you would do it in plain JS, then add types afterward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: No it's not possible without a reference to a constructible runtime value.

The reason is that TypeScript types only exist at compile time (not at runtime) and can't be used as values. In your example, `T` is only a type (not a runtime value). This is the JavaScript that your TypeScript program compilation would produce:

```js
class Bar {}

class Foo {
  constructor() { }
  create() {
    return new T();
  }
}

const bar = new Foo().create();
//                    ^^^^^^^^
// Exception is thrown: ReferenceError: T is not defined
```

You can see that `T` is a reference to a runtime value that doesn't exist, and so it throws a `ReferenceError` exception when the `create` method is invoked.

---

Instead, you can accept a constructible object (and its arguments) and return a constructed instance:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGwCWAjAGwgB4BYAKCigAUBDVWgWySggA9gIEATF1CWt0QEQUWghABtALpQAvGIkyANBSoAVeYpCryAPi0IIAdygAKAHRWw9JkgBcNW8wCU8g+oDcFCpgK0kFgAxODgoAG81KBRaXEwoTH5Y6GJNdk4eFnhkNCxcQgg9MyiqTEQUDGx8Ikd1XSoqKwsbBmZHbIq8uFQ6VohOVCRUvSiXRwBJHPFMCHVwEnUDSMoG-mB0VAQoI1MynMr8oktrZyQXbxWAXwpr8l9-QKgAIXoI2-uAlheALwiovc62G65iSQgQIigLSYAEZHBUcAgAObKKCg4SiKGMABMjgQ6EYeAgqDc4Vu73IAOAUDwrwUITgFkSAk4ZhexIulOptF+dNCjKSLJ+KIA5FjhSisecKEA)

```ts
type Constructible<
  Params extends readonly any[] = any[],
  T = any,
> = new (...params: Params) => T;

class Foo {
  static create <T extends Constructible>(
    constructible: T,
    ...params: ConstructorParameters<T>
  ): InstanceType<T> {
    return new constructible(...params);
  }
}

class Bar {}

class Baz {
  constructor (readonly param1: string, readonly param2: number) {}
}

const bar = Foo.create(Bar);
const baz = Foo.create(Baz, '2', 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't create any instance of a class without a runtime reference to that class constructor.

You could pass your class to be created as a value to the creator's constructor, and then generically capture that type's value.

I would make you `Constructor` non-generic, just to use it as a constraint, and let typescript infer the rest.

```
type Constructor = { new (...args: any[]): any };
```

For example:

```
class Foo<T extends Constructor> {
    constructor(private ctor: T) {}

    create(): InstanceType<T> {
        return new this.ctor();
    }
}
```

Which lets you do this:

```
class Bar { }

const foo = new Foo(Bar)
const bar1: Bar = foo.create(); // no parameters
const bar2: Bar = foo.create(); // no parameters
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=15&ssc=49&pln=11&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6qgXigG8oEIB3KACgDo6BDVAcyQC4p6EQBtAXQEp2nEFAC+AbgBQkzABt6SJFABicOAB4AKlAgAPYBAQATJfGRosOVAD5ikqA6iZEKDNlxUwqAJYA3egZOVuya-MSi0o5OqBABEFSCUACS5pyYEJrgEFq2RPZRjjHA6KgIpBRQwAAW3kg07qgJUlERETLyilAAQozEYtLO5lAAZmoE5ZSqcFQ9qPwyLsBQAEaMAIzss+OjcPUxcU1QAPRHpHBQYIz0ALYQBqhIC0OrqABMm72EO3uxBocnZwuV1u9yQQA)

---

For bonus points, you can pick up the constructor parameters and make your `create()` method take them:

```
    create(...ctorArgs: ConstructorParameters<T>): InstanceType<T> {
        return new this.ctor(...ctorArgs);
    }
```

Which let's you do:

```
class Bar {
    constructor(a: number, b: string) {}
}

const foo = new Foo(Bar)
const bar1: Bar = foo.create(1, 'a'); // no parameters
const bar2: Bar = foo.create(2, 'b'); // no parameters
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=55#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6qgXigG8oEIB3KACgDo6BDVAcyQC4p6EQBtAXQEp2nEFAC+AbgBQkzABt6SJFABicOAB4AKlAgAPYBAQATJfGRosOVAD5ikqA6iZEKDNlxUwqAJYA3egZOVuya-MSi0o5OqBABELR07qgAgsxssC4WSQAKjPQAthAGqEha1oJQAJLmnJgQmuAQZXZRUTHA6KgIpBRQwAAW3kg0SQkjVqks-FJREREy8opQAEKMLY7O5m5WVPTsCOj5AEYQqAA0UEfsrt4ITGFEc9KbKFAAZmoEPZSqcFSrqH4Mkyl0YAEZ2ACvh84CMYnEqGCLgByejI6ZQAD0mNIcCgYDyhWKSGB5lBqAATJC1oQYXDYgYqBSUUd0eIsTiEHiCagCkVTkggA)

Or you could put this in the creators constructor instead?

```
class Foo<T extends Constructor> {
    ctorArgs: ConstructorParameters<T>

    constructor(private ctor: T, ...ctorArgs: ConstructorParameters<T>) {
        this.ctorArgs = ctorArgs
    }

    create(): InstanceType<T> {
        return new this.ctor(...this.ctorArgs);
    }
}

class Bar {
    constructor(a: number, b: string) {}
}

const foo = new Foo(Bar, 1, 'a')
const bar1: Bar = foo.create(); // no parameters
const bar2: Bar = foo.create(); // no parameters
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=21&ssc=49&pln=3&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gOwM7AE4FcDGw6qgXigG8oEIB3KACgDo6BDVAcyQC4p6EQBtAXQEp2nEFAC+AbgBQkzABt6SJFABicOAB4AKlAgAPYBAQATJfGRosOVAD5ikqA6jZcAQWZtYiFBmeoACoz0ALYQBqhIWtbSjk5eFr5UYKgAlgBu9AZOVuyaADRQdDS+bizsZt6WuAGowaEQ4ZH8djExwAAWyUhFViVKhMXu9o6i0Y6YqBAZEFSCUACS5pyYEJrgEJHNLQ4TwOioCKQUUO2d3bi0dCddAyz8UjEjIzLyilAAQoybDphxPlZU9HYCHQQQARvV8qD2N5kggmE0iI9pD9zFAAGZqAiHSiqOBUD6ofIARnyAHJ6KT+DI4lBQYwiewCViMXAihMpjNxFAAPTc0hwKBgQIhMJIamoumoABMjM+hBZbMmBk5PL5CAFQpqIvqSCAA)